# Not able to insert data into postgresql table via python script

Tags: python, postgresql, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I want to insert data into Postgresql db table and return the id of that row using python command line interface.

The code runs via cmd :
**python final1.py -c configuration.yml -a 'ABC'**

I'm trying to load the configuration from the YAML file. -a is like a flag which indicates the data('ABC') needs to be inserted in the table

My file1.py python code:

```
# Import our libraries
import os
import sys
import argparse
import yaml

def add_file(configuration, studName):
    studName=str(studName)

    sql = '''INSERT INTO study(studName) VALUES(%s) RETURNING id);'''
 
    return select(configuration["connection_string"], sql, {'name':studName})

def load_configuration(configuration):
    try:
        with open(configuration, "r") as yamlfile:
            cfg = yaml.load(yamlfile)
            return cfg
    except Exception:
        print("Configuration file not found")
        exit(1)

def select(connectionString,sql,parameters):
    # Open the connection
    connection = psycopg2.connect(connectionString)
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql, (parameters,))
    
    study_id=cursor.fetchone()[0]
    
    connection.commit()
    
    cursor.close()
    
    return study_id


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Check the command line   

    # Parse the parameters
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-a', action='store', dest='studyname')
    
    parser.add_argument('-c', action='store', dest='conf_file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    #configuration=args.conf_file
    studies=0

    # Run the main function
    cfg = load_configuration(args.conf_file)
    studies = add_file(cfg, args.studyname)
    print(studies)
    #configuration = str(sys.argv[1:])
    #print(configuration)
```

My configuration file contains connection string:

```
connection_string:"host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=pass connect_timeout=60"
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
File "final1.py", line 64, in <module>
    studies = add_file(cfg, args.studyname)
  File "final1.py", line 19, in add_file
    return select(configuration["connection_string"], sql, {'name':studName})
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Please help

Comment: Maybe the port is missing? and also does it insert if you remove `RETURNING id`

Comment: Your yaml load is returning a string, not a dictionary.  Is that not what you expect?  By the way, there's a syntax error in your SQL.  You have a dangling close paren as the next-to-the-last character.

Comment: you missed the space after the colon in your yaml file, that's why it parsed as string

Answer (score 0):

As correctly mentioned by @NobbyNobbs, the connection string didn't have a space after colon. Also, as pointed out by @Tim Roberts my sql query had a close paren which was also the cause of the error. Thank you for pointing out the mistake :)